# Filtering query in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I would like to create a filtering query for one of my collections in mongoDB. Basically I want to retrieve every element in my collection except some field in all the documents. On the mongoDB spec it's written something like this:

`db.users.find({}, {thumbnail:0});`

But I would like to do more, I would like to filter for three different entries, something more like this:

`db.users.find({}, {thumbnail: 0, a: 0, b: 0});`

The problem is that this is not working. I keep receiving those fields after the query.

I also tried something like this:

`db.users.find({}, {{thumbnail: 0}, {a: 0}, {b: 0}});`

But mongoDB doesn't even accept something like this...

Can anyone help me?

Comment: The solution from the documentation works for me. What version of the mongodb do you use?

Comment: 2.0.1, the example is ok, but if I want to filter more than one thing away, it doesn't work the way I showed. Any suggestion?

Comment: @Masiar: very strange. Are you run your queries in mongodb shell or from some driver? Mb it is driver issue, because queries #1 and #2 work well in shell.

Comment: I just tried in the shell and the second one doesn't work. That's very strange indeed. I'm using both the shell and MongoSkin for Node.js

Comment: can you post your 'user' document structure?

Comment: Works for me with 2.0.1 running on linux64. What platform? Are you in the shell? Can you show me an example document in the collection?

Comment: tested in 2.0.0 shell. Everything is working correctly.

Comment: The data is a bit confidential, so I cannot really post it, but I discovered that the guy that generated the collection gave me the wrong information about the data structure. The format of the collection is something like this: `{_id: ..., "1" : {a : "a", b : "b", d : "d", ...} ... }` and so on, so I would like to filter out a and b, but is it possible to do it in a data structure like this?

Comment: @Masiar: yes, it's not possible. You can exclude entire root property, but not properties of embedded object.

Comment: @Masiar: answer your question yourself to not leave question unanswered.

Comment: @Andrew don't worry that's what I wanted to do as soon as I could :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wrote in the comments of the question, I discovered that the guy that generated the collection gave me the wrong information about the data structure. The format of the collection is something like this: `{_id: ..., "1" : {a : "a", b : "b", d : "d", ...}, ... }` and so on, thus it's not possible to filter for example elements `a` and `b` from the collection when entirely retrieving it.